# CacheServiceEmulator.exe >3GB RAM usage?

Tags: caching, azure, azure-caching

I am developing an application for windows azure using the latest SDK.
At the moment I am implementing the session provider using the cache, but the simulator is completely out of proportion:
[image]
The cache is implemented as a "very small" worker role (max. 768 MB RAM).

Does anyone know if this is normal or if I have some misconfiguration?

Answer (score 2):

While I can't say if this is the "*right*" behavior but I am also seeing the same. In my case, cacheserviceemulator.exe starts at about 300KB memory and keeps on consuming more and more memory. What I have been told is that it is expected behavior. This service is expected to `consume up to 30% of your system's memory` over an extended period of time.

One other note: I noticed that you're using `X-Small` Size instance for cache worker role. Please note that minimum size supported for caching is `Small`. Thought I should mention that as well.

Comment: About X-Small: It warns about bad performance with X-Small, but as I jsut use it for session storage that should be good enough...

Comment: Please see this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh914140.aspx. Here it says Extra Small instance is not supported. Have you tried deploying the code in Azure? I think you'll get an error at that time. We too thought that using X-Small should be fine but if I'm not mistaken we got an error on deploying the code on Azure (that was some time back).